# "font-not-found" when I have already install the font and I can't find ctex-xecjk-winfonts.def to change it

Tags: fonts, pandoc

When I ran:

```
pandoc --filter pandoc-crossref --filter pandoc-citeproc --biblio reference.bib --csl chinese-gb7714-2005-numeric.csl --latex-engine=xelatex --template=cqu.latex main.md -o main.pdf
```

the terminal showed:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "[simfang]" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................                                                    

l.68 ...bold\zhttfont{[simfang.ttf]}{[simkai.ttf]}
```

but I have already installed the font.
I searched and found someone said I should go to `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-xecjk-winfonts.def` and change `[SIMKAI.TTF]`，`[SIMFANG.TTF]` to `KaiTi`，`FangSong`.
But there is 2017 in textlive and there is  `ctex-fontset-mac.def,ctex-fontset-windows.def`, `ctex-fontset-windowsnew.def`, `ctex-fontset-windowsold.def` in `fontset`. When I open them, there is no `[SIMKAI.TTF]` or `[SIMFANG.TTF]`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Maybe also https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-with-Chinese

Comment: @mb21 [github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-with-Chinese](github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-with-Chinese) suggests install package ctex. I searched ctex and found [download center:CTEX](http://www.ctex.org/CTeXDownload/), there is .exe in it but I use Mac. And if I add `-V CJKmainfont=WenQuanYi\ Micro\ Hei\ Mono`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: try `tlgmr install ctex`

Comment: Don't use ctex: ctex is a custom engine pretty much for "only Chinese", and pretty much useless for real international latex typesetting. For that, you want xelatex, which you're clearly already using. Step 1: this is *clearly* a fontspec package error, so you want to ask the people on the [TeX stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com) on how to solve this. And optional step 2, you want to google for this error in relation to pandoc.